# what is best practice for backup restore on. FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, backup, snapshot, restore

What is the best practice for system backup and restore on freebsd?
Because I'm making many changes to the system I need to use quickest and easiest way to restore entire system to previous configuration (same was as is done for example on vmware snapshots)
Does dump and restore is best way?

Thanks

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information in this question for evaluating "best", which of course depends from needs and circumstances.  For example: Do you have ZFS for all of your filesystems, including the root filesystem?  What version of FreeBSD is this? You need to [edit] your question and tell people things like this.

Comment: Consider configuration management tools.

Comment: Are the changes to the system, or to just one user?

Answer (score 1):

As always, [the FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/backup-basics.html) should be your first resource for looking into these things.

> The traditional UNIX® programs for backing up a file system are
> dump(8), which creates the backup, and restore(8), which restores the
> backup.

And this works great for many cases. Some people might just tar certain directories, such as /etc and /usr/local/etc and /usr/home along with any data directories they may have but this all varies user to user.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ZFS you can just create filesystem snapshots

```
zfs snapshot zroot/whateverPool@yourSnapshotName
```